# Use formulas on rendered/display value of an excel cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column in Excel with Currency values. They are formatted to 2 decimal places and have a currency code prefix (using the "Format Cells" option).

For example, the raw value:

```
10000
```

gets displayed as:

```
ZMW 10,000.00
```

Please note this is done using formatting, not a formula.

Now I want to use the display value of this cell (i.e. ZMW 10,000.00) in a formula in another cell (e.g. =LEFT($A$1, 3)).
However the formula always works on the raw value of the cell, not its display value.

I tried multiple options, but wasn't able to get a formula working in excel on display value of a cell. Can someone please advice how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest method of retrieving the displayed text (not the raw value) from any formatted cell is the [Range.Text property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.text).

**Module1 code sheet**

```
Option Explicit

Function cellText(rng As Range)

    cellText = rng.Text

End Function
```

In the following, A1 has a custom number format of `Z\MW #,##0.00` and a raw value of 10000.

```
=LEFT(cellText(A1), 3)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi  @user11262953, thanks for your helpful reply. Any way to accomplish this without using VBA?